# self referential structures in C

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures, linked-list

I want to declare a self-referential structure as below

```
    typedef struct
    {
            entry_t *entry;
            node_t *next;
    }node_t;
```

instead of as below for a linked-list

```
  struct node
  {
         entry_t *entry;
         struct node *next;
  }*head;
```

does this work in C? If no why not?

Comment: *does this work in C?* -- why not just try it first?

Comment: @liv2hak: apparently you can somehow manage to do it (using an incomplete type and a forward-declaration); see my answer.

Answer (score 6):

It won't work, since the symbol/name `node_t` is unknown at the declaration of `next`:

```
typedef struct
{
    entry_t *entry;
    node_t *next; /* <-- Error: unknown type */
} node_t;
```

Your struct needs a name in its declaration in order to be "self referential". However, you can keep the typedef:

```
typedef struct node
{
    entry_t *entry;
    struct node *next; /* <-- type struct node is known */
} node_t;
```

Now you can use either `struct node` or `node_t` to create a new node.

Comment: Just to add, C is different here from C++, where you do not need to use `typedef` specifically. In C, once `typedef` is encountered, `node_t` will be equivalent to `struct node`.

Comment: @Zeta you can also use a forward declaration, see my answer.

Comment: @H2CO3: +1, but only if OP "*really, badly* want[s] that typedeffed name as early as declaring the structure itself", yes. Personally, I prefer to use the first variant you mentioned, as I like to fully define the structure before or at the same time I use a typedef. But I guess that's a question of coding style :D

Comment: @Zeta me too, I prefer the complete-type one, but I wanted to answer OP's question instead of teaching him good practice :D

Comment: @Zeta, @H2CO3: actually, I think it's pretty common to put the `typedef struct foo foo_t;` line in a public header, leaving `foo_t` as an incomplete type. That works fine as long as the public interface only uses `foo_t*s`' and avoids having to put any details about `foo_t` in a public header. The actual `struct foo` definition can go in a library internal header.

Answer (score 4):

The version you mentioned for the 2nd time is widely used, you **can** make a typedef like

```
typedef struct some_struct_name {
    /* other fields, etc... */
    struct some_struct_name *next;
} *some_type;
```

If you **really, badly** want that typedeffed name as early as declaring the structure itself, you can use a forward declaration using an incomplete type:

```
typedef struct node *node_t;

struct node {
    int data;
    node_t next;
};
```

This is also accepted by C89:

[image]

Comment: @caf you don't need to sniff at every and each thing I do.

Comment: no need to make the `typedef` a pointer to `struct`. Just a normal `typedef` as forward declaration of the `struct` and the `typedef` would do.